# Synchronizing Solr Commit

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have multiple Java tasks that access solr and write and commit some documents sequentially. Often these tasks change the same document. My problem is that one task may trigger a commit, terminates, pass the control to the other task which in turn issue another commit. When the first commit isn't done before the second task starts, I get solr lock timeout exception.

One solution I was investigating is to have each of these tasks simply do an update and no commit. The problem, however is that changes by early tasks are not visible to later tasks. Thus the later tasks end up overwriting some of the changes done by the previous ones.

Now, I am investigating  whether I can detect the end of each commit before triggering the next task. Any idea?

How would you guys resolve this problem?

These tasks are off-the-shelf non-trivial components that i cannot really change.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sound like you are trying to have the commit happen in the background after the "task" terminates.  You'd be better off doing the commit synchronously; i.e. don't terminate the task until the commit has succeeded (or failed).  (I'll admit that I don't use Solr, and I don't know how you would map those ideas to the Solr APIs.)

Comment: Yes, this is right.  Explicit Solr commits are synchronous by default so you must be doing something out of the ordinary like waitSearcher=false to get other behavior, or you are doing the tasks in separate threads that aren't coordinated.  When you are ready to consider Solr 4, there is a new so-called "realtime get" feature in which you can query Solr for a document that has bet added but isn't yet searchable.

Comment: Are you suggesting that even when using HTTP, Solr will release the connection only after the commit is complete? Woudln't a short HTTP timeout be a challenge to this? Any reference on this topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes ... a short HTTP timeout would be a problem for this.  But this is the client's responsibility.  The client should be checking the HTTP response's status code, and if it doesn't get a response due to a timeout it shouldn't be assuming that the commit worked.  Setting a timeout that is too short is obviously counter-productive.